# I'm getting a VSCode python error, does anyone know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

```
& : The term 'usr/local/bin/python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & usr/local/bin/python3 "c:/Users/Syed Subhan Shakir/Downloads/Spring ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (usr/local/bin/python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is this? I haven't changed anything since it last run

Comment: What exactly did you run?

Comment: everything i run returns this error, just regular simple code for assignments and stuff. I tried restarting VSCode but it didn't change anything

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Linux paths to `python3` in Windows, and it can't find the executable. Double check the settings to ensure the path to `python3` is correct for your system.

Comment: Also, if you were on a Linux distribution, you'd need (it most circumstances) a `/` before `usr` to ensure that the path is absolute and not relative to the current working directory.

Comment: What the heck? Where did Linux come from? how do i remove that?

Comment: Is it something that you copied the codebase from somewhere or developing the codebase in a team and somehow and the `.vscode` directory is also there (maybe someone pushed .vscode directory also)? If yes then please remove the directory and reconfigure.

Comment: Yes it is actually. How do I remove the directory and reconfigure?

Comment: @Syed Shakir -Is the relevant python path set in the settings file "settings.json" in VS Code? Please provide us with the content of "settings.json".